# Installing Farbtastic on Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, colorbox, color-picker, color-wheel

Trying to install Farbtastic color-picker plugin in my Wordpress site, but have no success with it.

It seems that I'm doing everything as tutorial is saying, but color wheel does not appear, only form with a default value.

Here's the code I'm using:

Include farbtastic.js and farbtastic.css in your HTML  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="farbtastic/farbtastic.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="farbtastic/farbtastic.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Add a placeholder div and a text field to your HTML, and give each an ID:

```
<form><input type="text" id="color" name="color" value="#123456" /></form>
<div id="colorpicker"></div>
```

Include this in your HTML  tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');
   });
</script>
```

Please help someone, because I feel there's stupid mistake somewhere, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the relative paths "farbtastic/farbtastic.*" are not relative to the current page.

Comment: It's actually now on localhost, so it would be a little bit difficult to show you page in live right now.

But when I'm looking in source code and click on a link where farbtastic.js and farbtastic.css beeing imported, links are working perfectly, files are showed to me. Or does this means nothing?

Comment: Well if they are shown, they should work. So this might be not the problem. Did you check for other Errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: Hmm.. Chrome shows me error: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'farbtastic'.

Comment: What the Error means is that the Plugin is most likely not loaded, or you are calling it on a non valid object (what is unlikely in jQuery) so we are again on my first answer. Did you tried absolute paths yet? like lets say you put the farbtastic dir in the root (/) you can use /farbtastic/*** instead of without starting /

Comment: Yeah, I did that. But now it shows me another error: "Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function" on the string "$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');".

Comment: I wrote that code like this: "jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#colorpicker').farbtastic('#color');". But now it shows me this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'farbtastic' of undefined." Damn, it starts to drive me crazy.

Comment: please try to isolate the code to a JSFiddle, its really hard to help this way :3